# How to identify a "preferred" child on a parent record maintaining referential integrity?

Tags: sql-server, referential-integrity

I am defining an entity which represents a Page which consists of one or more Part items.  Every Page must have at least one Part defined.  Each Part belongs to only one Page.  One of the Part items will be the "master" Part on the page, and all others will rely on the master.  Other than this difference, the master and slave parts behave identically.

I'm looking at a couple of different ways to express this in SQL.  I can think of a couple of options, each with advantages and disadvantages.  I'm sure there's no one "right answer," but I'm looking for feedback on which approaches have hidden complexities that will bite me in the butt later.  Constraints and CASCADE triggers are desirable, so that other parties can safely modify the tables when needed, but I'd like to avoid a design that requires twisty, complex logic.

At configuration time, the user needs the ability to choose the master without allowing 0 or multiple parts to be marked as primary.  At runtime, each part needs to identify if it is the master, or needs to rely on the master for information.

My target platform is Microsoft SQL Server 2008 or higher.  The samples below use int keys simply because it makes for smaller examples -- I would tend toward GUID keys at implementation.

**Option 1 - flag on master part**

```
create table [Page] (
  PageKey int identity primary key,
  PageName varchar(30) not NULL
)
go
create table [Part] (
  PartKey int identity primary key,
  PartName varchar(30) not NULL,
  PageKey int not null,
  constraint fkPage foreign key (PageKey) references [Page](PageKey),
  IsMasterPart bit not NULL default 0
)
```

Advantages: simple to understand in data; similar approach used in the base application I am enhancing; the Part record knows it is master without looking up data on the Page record.
Disadvantages:  Forcing one-and-only-one master would require triggers to reject updates which violate the rule, or application-layer code, or both.

**Option 2 - foreign key on page**

```
create table [Page] (
  PageKey int identity primary key,
  PageName varchar(30) not NULL,
  MasterPartKey int not NULL
)
go
create table [Part] (
  PartKey int identity primary key,
  PartName varchar(30) not NULL,
  PageKey int not null,
  constraint fkPage foreign key (PageKey) references [Page](PageKey),
  IsMasterPart bit not NULL default 0
)
go
alter table [Page] 
  add constraint fkMasterPart 
  foreign key (MasterPartKey) references [Part](PartKey)
```

Advantages:  DRI protects against deleting the master part; can only have one master part; cannot have a Page without a master Part
Disadvantages:  Potential chicken-and-egg problem with assigning PK/FK values

- What is the pattern (or is there one) for inserting a parent and the first mandatory child in one operation?
- What is the pattern (or is there one) for deleting the last child and the parent, that will still prevent deleting the Page and master Part when other Parts exist?

I suspect I've missed one or two details that are necessary to give a good answer.  Please ask away and I'll update.

Comment: it's comments like this that distract me before getting to the heart of the question >  "I would tend toward GUID keys at implementation". Now I want to put aside your question and talk about that comment. Why would you go for GUIDs over ints? [Ever-increasing clustering key – the Clustered Index Debate……….again! - Kimberly Tripp](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-clustered-index-debate-again/)

Comment: I guess I muddied the water with that comment. It wasn't really relevant, but I will definitely read up on your links before I move forward. Thanks!

Comment: I read through your article, and I appreciate the comments about page splitting (really, because I preach that too).  In my scenario, the largest table will contain only hundreds of rows, possibly thousands if I'm optimistic.  it's more important to have key values assigned that can be "upserted" blind into another database (maintaining cross-references) than to have a uniformly increasing key.  Setup data, not transaction data. Thanks for the pushback, though. That's what I came here for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with Option 1.   Your disadvantage to Option 1 is not correct:   The "one and only one master" rule can be enforced with a CHECK CONSTRAINT that calls a UDF.  And that's what I would use.

Comment: What about if they want to make a different part the master? Is there a good way to perform this atomically?  Maybe setting the flag on a new Part clears it out on the old master, or should I write an update... set IsMasterPart = (1 - IsMasterPart) where PartKey in (@old, @new)  ?

Comment: It could be done atomically (I think) with a carefully-constructed UPDATE:  `SET IsMasterPart=CASE WHEN somecondtion THEN 1 ELSE 0 END...`